# Operation timed out while using HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse and Streamreader separately

Tags: c#, php, httpwebrequest, streamreader, httpwebresponse

So I am currently using a HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse system to send information to a php document while using a different system using Streamreader to get information from a different php document. These php files deal with stats from an icecast stream.

The Request/Response system can be called from certain commands sending different information with different instances of the system through my code. The code is set up like this then altered for the different commands:

```
string newURL = "setStat.php?type=type1&n=" + stats;
HttpWebRequest wrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(newURL);
HttpWebResponse wresponse = (HttpWebResponse)wrequest.GetResponse();
Stream resStream = wresponse.GetResponseStream();
```

The Streamreader system is called every time the song from the icecast stream has changed to grab new stats from the current song. The code is set up like this:

```
WebClient web = new WebClient();
using (StreamReader status = new StreamReader(web.OpenRead("icecast.php")))
{
    string line = string.Empty;
    while ((line = status.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        ...
    }
    status.Close();
}
```

Now I use to get the error "System.Net.WebException: The operation timed out" after a lot of commands with the Request/Response was used and that error would fall on my Streamreader line:

```
using (StreamReader status = new StreamReader(web.OpenRead("icecast.php")))
```

Then last night I found what I thought to be my solution to this operation timed out issue. I came across a different question that suggested the use of:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit
```

So I added that to my code at the start of my initialize function and set it equal to 10, I figured it would be overkill and but would work since I figured I only really need 2 as far as I understood it. It seemed my issue was gone until a few hours ago it came back. I am starting to wonder if I just don't have enough connections and my limit is causing it or if there is a better way to have these two separate systems work without interrupting each other. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: `WebClient` is `IDisposable`. If you're not disposing of it, you might be leaking resources.

Comment: Hmm, well I can try that but I won't really know if it worked unless I see the error display again. Like I said I thought it was fixed but then I saw that error message pop up after a few hours of moderate use of commands.

Comment: Well it would seem I got the same result even after updating the `WebClient` to use `Dispose()`. The application timed out after about 4-5 hours of use.